# What is a nice way to put all files in a directory into an environment variable?

Tags: bash

Right now, I have a fairly gross solution which is:

```
FILES=" "
for f in `find $DIR -type f`; do FILES=$FILES$f" "; done
```

(note that I do want a space in between each)

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: What is the use case?  This might be an X-Y problem.

Comment: How do you want to use this `FILES` variable later?

Comment: You can't cleanly *store* an arbitrary list of files in a single string, so there's little point is asking for a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use command substitution:

```
FILES=$(find "$DIR" -type f)
```

Be careful with this, though. Using space as the delimiter between filenames means you won't be able to deal with filenames that contain spaces in them. So this is only usable in a context where you know that filenames are formatted simply. For more general situations, you should use an array.

Comment: beautiful... I knew there was a cleaner way!

Comment: @AQuestionAsker That's actually not clean at all. It might look nice, but it puts no care to file names with white-spaces, therefore it will be impossible to recreate the list of files out of `FILES`, moreover, in Bash you have arrays, which are much more convenient and correct.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein His original loop also doesn't work with filenames that have whitespace, so I assume he doesn't care about that.

Comment: @Barmar I respect the way you prefer to write your answers, as long as I can comment about bad practices I find dangerous. Generally, I recommend incorporating best practices when writing any good example or a solution for a specific problem, so that one could learn how to *understand a concept*, rather than attack a specific problem, to which a "Just OK" solution works.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a caveat. You might want to post an answer that shows the complete solution using an array.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks you for editing your answer and emphasizing this subject. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using a recent version of `bash`, you can dispense with `find` altogether and use an array.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && FILES+=("$f")
done
```